# how to permanently hold values in form

Tags: javascript, html

after the submit button is clicked, the values gotten from the javascript does not stay in the input areas. they just appear for about a second and then disappear.

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
 <title> Assignment Solution on Programming the Internet (Week 4)
 </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

<style>
 textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

#d{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
}
#dd{
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="JavaScriptValidation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div  id="d">
<h1>Type a Phrase, Count the Vowels</h1>
<form >
<!-- onsubmit = "return validateJS()" -->

 <fieldset> 
    <legend> </legend>
        <p>Input of >=10 Characters Which Includes Vowels</p>
        <textarea id="t" placeholder="Type your word(s)"></textarea>
 </fieldset> 
 <div id="dd">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> The number of vowels</legend>

<!-- <textarea name="p" id="p" rows = "1" cols = "15"></textarea><br /> -->

        <label for="surname"> Letter "a"</label><br />
        <input name = "a" id = "a" type = "text" size ="20" maxlength = "30" value="@Request["inputText"]"/><br />

        <label for="surname"> Letter "e"</label><br />
        <input name = "surname" id = "e" type = "text" size ="20" maxlength = "30" /><br />

        <label for="surname"> Letter "i"</label><br />
        <input name = "surname" id = "i" type = "text" size ="20" maxlength = "30" /><br />

        <label for="surname"> Letter "o"</label><br />
        <input name = "surname" id = "o" type = "text" size ="20" maxlength = "30" /><br />

        <label for="surname"> Letter "u"</label><br />
        <input name = "surname" id = "u" type = "text" size ="20" maxlength = "30" /><br />
    </fieldset>

    <p><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Count Vowels" onclick="countVowels()" /></p>
 </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

the javascript:

```
function validateJS() {
   validateTextBoxes();
   return (validateTextBoxes());
}

function validateTextBoxes() {
var all_input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var completed = true;

// for (i = 0; i < all_input.length; i++){
//    if (all_input[i].type === "text"){
//       if (all_input[i].value === ""){
//           alert("You have not filled in "+i+" text box(es)"+u);
//           completed = false;
//         }
//    }
// }
return completed;
}

function countVowels(){
    var z = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var a = z.split("a").length;
    var u = a-1;

    var b = z.split("e").length;
    var c = b-1;

    var d = z.split("i").length;
    var f = d-1;

    var g = z.split("o").length;
    var h = g-1;

    var i = z.split("u").length;
    var j = i-1;

var m = Math.max(u, c, f, h, j);
// document.getElementById("p").value = u;
document.getElementById("a").value = u;
document.getElementById("e").value = c;
document.getElementById("i").value = f;
document.getElementById("o").value = h;
document.getElementById("u").value = j;

if (z.length == 0){
    alert("You have not filled in the text box.");
}

if (m == c){
document.getElementById("b").style.backgroundColor = "red";
alert(l+"no of a: "+u+"   no of e: "+c+"   no of i: "+f+"   no of o: "+h+"   no of u: "+j);
}

alert(l+"no of a: "+u+"   no of e: "+c+"   no of i: "+f+"   no of o: "+h+"   no of u: "+j);

 return false;
}
```

pls help. thanks

Comment: Try changing the submit button to type button

Answer (score 0):

You lose the values because the page is being submitted by the form. 
You will have to return false on form submit so it wont navigate again.
You should do the following

`<form onsubmit="return countVowels();">`

and as I can see in your code you have unhandled exceptions that will never allow your code to `return false`.

I would suggest

```
function countVowels() {

    try {
        var z = document.getElementById("t").value;
        var a = z.split("a").length;
        var u = a - 1;

        var b = z.split("e").length;
        var c = b - 1;

        var d = z.split("i").length;
        var f = d - 1;

        var g = z.split("o").length;
        var h = g - 1;

        var i = z.split("u").length;
        var j = i - 1;
        debugger;
        var m = Math.max(u, c, f, h, j);
        // document.getElementById("p").value = u;
        document.getElementById("a").value = u;
        document.getElementById("e").value = c;
        document.getElementById("i").value = f;
        document.getElementById("o").value = h;
        document.getElementById("u").value = j;

        if (z.length == 0) {
            alert("You have not filled in the text box.");
        }

        if (m == c) {
            document.getElementById("b").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            alert(l + "no of a: " + u + "   no of e: " + c + "   no of i: " + f + "   no of o: " + h + "   no of u: " + j);
        }

        alert(l + "no of a: " + u + "   no of e: " + c + "   no of i: " + f + "   no of o: " + h + "   no of u: " + j);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You send your form before onclick event.

What you should is: make a button that is not *type="submit"*

add onclick event to it (just like you already have)

add ID to your form

and add this to your scipt (in the end):

```
var form = document.getElementById("form-id");
form.submit();
```